the_permalink method in wordpress not working as expected?
this is my section-archive.php file. when I click on button, it doesn't show anything.
<?php if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<div id="archive-section" class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-dody">
        <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">ادامه مطلب</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php  endwhile; endif;?>

I want the rest of the article to be shown on a new page by clicking on the continue reading button.

The button ادامه مطلب leads to the post in the same page. Do you want the link to open in a new tab? Just add a target="_blank" to your link.

get_permalink, needs an id as a parameter, get_the_permalink uses the current post id.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/
